# Normalize Deep nested data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, normalization, normalizr

I need to normalize the api response data with deeply nested structure.
I am using this https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr to normalize my data.

I have a input data as

```
const data = [{
  id: 'component1,
  name: 'component one,
  properties:[{
    name: 'text',
    color: 'red'
  }]
},
{
  id: 'component2,
  name: 'component two',
  properties:[{
    name: 'text',
    color: 'yellow'
  },{
    name: 'button',
    color: 'blue'
  }]
}]
```

Expected output after normalization

```
    { 
      entities: {
        component1: {
           id: 'component1,
           name: 'component one,
           properties: {
             entities: {
               text: {
                  name: 'text',
                  color: 'red'
               }
             },
             results: ['text']
           }
        },
        component2: {
           id: 'component2,
           name: 'component two,
           properties: {
             entities: {
               text: {
                  name: 'text',
                  color: 'yellow'
               },
               button: {
                 name: 'button',
                 color: 'blue'
               }
             },
             results: ['text', 'button']
           }
        }
      },
      results: ['component1', 'component2']
    }
```

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach, iterate all data using `forEach()` in order to rearrange it in the format you want:

```js
const data = [{id: 'component1',name: 'component one',properties:[{name: 'text',color: 'red'}]},{id: 'component2',name: 'component two',properties:[{name: 'text',color: 'yellow'},{name: 'button',color: 'blue'}]}];

let result = {entities: {}, result: []};
data.forEach(c => {
  result.result.push(c.id);
  result.entities[c.id] = {
    id: c.id,
    name: c.name,
    properties: {
      entities: Object.fromEntries(c.properties.map(p => [p.name, p])),
      results: c.properties.map(p => p.name)
    }
  };
});

console.log(result);
```